# How to handle type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic> exception flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, crud

I am trying to display the list of info from API.  I have created an API and model and provider classes respectively. When I try to access the API I am getting this:

> "List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>"

where my API response is given below

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "naveen",
        "email": "demo@email.com",
        "scheduledDate": "15-09-2022",
        "remarks": "demo",
        "createdAt": "2022-09-14T23:57:09.344Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-09-14T23:57:09.344Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "naveen",
        "email": "demo@email.com",
        "scheduledDate": "16-09-2022",
        "remarks": "demo",
        "createdAt": "2022-09-14T23:57:17.756Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-09-14T23:57:17.756Z"
    }
]
```

and my model class

```
class ScheduleListModel {
  int? id;
  String? username;
  String? email;
  String? scheduledDate;
  String? remarks;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;

  ScheduleListModel(
      {this.id,
      this.username,
      this.email,
      this.scheduledDate,
      this.remarks,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt});

  ScheduleListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    username = json['username'];
    email = json['email'];
    scheduledDate = json['scheduledDate'];
    remarks = json['remarks'];
    createdAt = json['createdAt'];
    updatedAt = json['updatedAt'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['username'] = username;
    data['email'] = email;
    data['scheduledDate'] = scheduledDate;
    data['remarks'] = remarks;
    data['createdAt'] = createdAt;
    data['updatedAt'] = updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}
```

and provider class

```
class ScheduleListProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool isBack = false;
  late ScheduleListModel scheduleListModel;
  ScheduleListModel get getScheduleListModel => scheduleListModel;
  Future<void> getAllScheduleListData() async {
    getAllSchedule().then((response) => {
          if (response!.statusCode == 200)
            {
              scheduleListModel =
                  ScheduleListModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)),
              notifyListeners(),
            }
        });
  }
}
```

This is my API call

```
Future<http.Response?> getAllSchedule() async {
  late SharedPreferences logindata;
  logindata = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  late String? token = logindata.getString('token');
  http.Response? response;
  try {
    response = await http.get(Uri.parse(Config.getAllScheduleAPI), headers: {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
      'x-access-token': '$token',
    });
  } catch (e) {
    log(e.toString());
  }
  return response;
}
```

When am trying to do API call am getting exception as:

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your api response is `List<ScheduleListModel>`, not a single ScheduleListModel. Thats why

```
ScheduleListModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)),
```

throws this error message.
Depending on what you want to do with the list, you should change `getAllScheduleListData()` to something which can work with a list of `ScheduleListModel`.

Comment: in provider class?

Comment: yes its in provider class

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class ScheduleListProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

bool isBack = false;
  List<ScheduleListModel> scheduleList = [];

  Future<void> getAllScheduleListData() async {
    getAllSchedule().then((response) => {
      if (response!.statusCode == 200) {
          json.decode(response.body).forEach((element){
            scheduleList.add(ScheduleListModel.fromJson(element));
          });
          notifyListeners(),
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The method 'forEach' isn't defined for the type 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'forEach'

this is what i get when i implement

Comment: user json.decode(response.body) @saravananG